# Converting an Empty String to Float

Tags: python

so I found a calculator I created a few years ago in Python and I decided to run it but it isn't working anymore. I am trying to fix it because I want to get back into programming.

Here is some of my code from the program:

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

display = Entry(master, width=15, justify="right", bd=0, bg="lightgrey")

master.title("Calculator")

class Calculator:

    def __init__(self): # the method called when we create our calculator method
        self.var1="" # first variable of the calculator
        self.var2=""
        self.result=0 # the result of the last equation
        self.current=0 # the current variable ur on
        self.operator=0 # the number of the operator

    def numb_butt(self, index): # will take index as a parameter and add it to the proper variable
        if self.current == 0:
            self.var1 = str(self.var1) + str(index)
            display.delete(0, END)
            display.insert(0, string=self.var1)
        else:
            self.var2 = str(self.var2) + str(index)
            display.delete(0, END)
            display.insert(0, string=self.var2)

    def equate(self): # find out what operator we're using and add, subtract, etc
        if self.operator == 0:
            self.result = float(self.var1) + float(self.var2)
        elif self.operator == 1:
            self.result = float(self.var1) - float(self.var2)
        elif self.operator == 2:
            self.result = float(self.var1)* float(self.var2)
        elif self.operator == 3:
            self.result = float(self.var1) / float(self.var2)
    display.delete(0, END)
    display.insert(0, string=self.result)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
    return self.func(*args)

      File "calculator.py", line 33, in equate
    self.result = float(self.var1)* float(self.var2)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

It doesn't solely happen with multiplication, it is now happening with all operations

Comment: would be great if you provided a [mre], but basically the error is simply saying that at the time of conversion either `self.var1` or `self.var2` (or both) were empty strings, basically they didn't hold any value, probably because no value was entered so please provide a [mre]

Comment: Do `float(self.var1 or "0")`. An empty string is falsy, so `or` returns the second operand "0" only if `self.var1` is falsy.

Comment: It's not clear what you want or expect to happen instead. I mean, `''` _isn't_ a float, so it's normal and correct for an exception to be thrown when you tell the interpreter to treat it as if it were.

Comment: I am trying to do mathematical operations, specifically here multiplication. For example 5 x 5  will just show up as 55 and produce an error.

Here is an image of what happens when I did 5 x 5
https://imgur.com/a/S4XL9cR

Answer (score 0):

Why not just init var1 & var2 as floats from the beginning instead of strings?

```
var1 = float(0)
var2 = float(0)
```

Comment: self.var1=float(0) # first variable of the calculator
self.var2=float(0)

Like this? Then delete all the string and float conversions below?

Comment: mathematical operations still don't work well.